# PhpStorm : How to recover the shelved changes ?

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm

I'm using PHPStorm when my laptop's battery suddenly died.

After going back home to recharge it I was in for a surprise: All my Shelved Changes are now GONE!

Is there any way I can recover them?

Also, when I booted up PHPStorm, it said something about `"workspace.xml"` being remade again.

I have a considerable amount of code shelved. Please help me :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Shelved changes are stored together with IDE-wide settings and not on per-project level (`.idea` subfolder).

- **OS X**: `Preferences/WebIdeXX/shelf`
- **Windows/Linux**: `~/.WebIdeXX/system/shelf`

---

**UPDATE 2021-04-08:**

Over the time the path where IDE stores global settings has changed quite a bit, especially for Linux and Windows since 2020.1 version.

Current paths can be seen here:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/tuning-the-ide.html#default-dirs

**P.S.** If installed via [JetBrains ToolBox App](https://www.jetbrains.com/toolbox-app/) then the path might be even more different (mainly applies to the settings and not system dirs though).

Comment: Awesome! You saved me a bunch of code. For anyone reading this, it is actually .WebIDEXX/CONFIG/shelf (at least on windows)

Comment: Since I'm not using shelved functionality myself .. it could be located in "config" folder indeed (cannot confirm myself, sorry .. but it **should be** in "system" folder if following the nature of the files). I took my info from another place which was given by actual PhpStorm dev a year or two ago.